Solving polynomial equations in Tate algberas
Let $A$ be a complete discrete valuation ring (or the ring of integers of a local non-archimedean field $K$), and let $B$ be a finite totally ramified extension of $A$. Fix a uniformizer $\varpi$ of $A$, so $B$ has a uniformizer $\pi=\sqrt[m]{\varpi}$ for some $m$. Let $R$ be an $A$-algebra of finite type, so $R$ takes the form $$R=A[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots,f_r).$$ Let $\hat{R}$ be the $\varpi$-completion of $R$; so $\hat{R}$ is the Tate algebra $$\hat{R}=A\left<x_1,\dots,x_n\right>/(f_1,\dots,f_r).$$ Suppose we have an inclusion $B\subset \hat{R}$ as $A$-algebras; this simply means the equation $T^m-\varpi=0$ has a solution in $\hat{R}$. My questions is: is the equation $T^m-\varpi=0$ solvable in $R$? Or in other words, based on my assumptions, is there an inclusion $B\subset R$ of $A$-algebras?

Doesn't seem likely. Did you look at an example already, with m=2?
